# Pass argument to deeply nested query

Tags: mysql, subquery

This overly complex query seems to work when I use a hardcoded value for `gid=node.nid` (eg. `gid=123`), but when I use it like below, I get the error following:

`Unknown column 'node.nid' in 'where clause'`

Edit: Important! This query is used in an even bigger query which has the `node.nid` in the overall query. And I know that the value is available in the most upper queries.

I assume this is due to scoping, though I'm not sure how to pass this node.nid to the deeper queries. If there is any way to reduce this to a lot smaller simpler query, I'd be all ears.

```
    ( 
       # Sum up all the user session counts to create a total 
       SELECT Sum(user_session_count) 
        FROM   node AS n1, 
               ( 
               # Filter out only the highest value for session_count per user, since that is the amount of sessions for one user, course completed or not.
               SELECT Max(session_count) user_session_count, 
                      uid, 
                      nid 
                FROM   node AS n2, 
                       ( 
                       # Returns the count of results, grouped by lesson nid. This way, we know that like 1/3 lessons have been run eg. 3 times, but 2/3 only 2 times. Therefor we can say we detected 3 sessions, which not all completed, but have started
                       SELECT Count(qnr.result_id) session_count, 
                              qnr.uid, 
                              qnr.nid 
                        FROM   node AS n3, 
                               quiz_node_results qnr 
                        WHERE  nid IN ( 
                                      # Returns all the nid's from the course's quizes 
                                      SELECT n4.nid 
                                       FROM   `og_membership` AS ogm 
                                              JOIN `node` AS n4 
                                                ON ogm.etid = n4.nid 
                                       WHERE  gid = node.nid 
                                              AND field_name = 'og_group_ref' 
                                              AND entity_type = 'node' 
                                              AND n4.type = 'quiz') 
                               AND qnr.uid IN ( 
                                              # Return all uid's in the class 
                                              SELECT ogm.etid 
                                               FROM   `og_membership` AS ogm 
                                               WHERE  gid = 983 
                                                      AND entity_type = 'user' 
                                                      AND field_name = 
                                                          'og_user_node') 
                        GROUP  BY qnr.nid, 
                                  qnr.uid 
                        ORDER  BY qnr.uid, 
                                  session_count DESC) t 
                GROUP  BY t.uid) t2)
```

*Edit 2*: Updated above query with latest version, based on the comments. For completeness sake, including the surrounding SQL, the final query would look as follows. Please note that I do not have permissions to alter the super query, only the subquery `courses_started`.

```
SELECT node.title                                                   AS 
       node_title, 
       node.nid                                                     AS nid, 
       node.created                                                 AS 
       node_created, 
       ( 
       # Sum up all the user session counts to create a total 
       SELECT Sum(user_session_count) 
        FROM   node AS n1, 
               ( 
               # Filter out only the highest value for session_count per user, since that is the amount of sessions for one user, course completed or not.
               SELECT Max(session_count) user_session_count, 
                      uid, 
                      nid 
                FROM   node AS n2, 
                       ( 
                       # Returns the count of results, grouped by lesson nid. This way, we know that like 1/3 lessons have been run eg. 3 times, but 2/3 only 2 times. Therefor we can say we detected 3 sessions, which not all completed, but have started
                       SELECT Count(qnr.result_id) session_count, 
                              qnr.uid, 
                              qnr.nid 
                        FROM   node AS n3, 
                               quiz_node_results qnr 
                        WHERE  nid IN ( 
                                      # Returns all the nid's from the course's quizes 
                                      SELECT n4.nid 
                                       FROM   `og_membership` AS ogm 
                                              JOIN `node` AS n4 
                                                ON ogm.etid = n4.nid 
                                       WHERE  gid = node.nid 
                                              AND field_name = 'og_group_ref' 
                                              AND entity_type = 'node' 
                                              AND n4.type = 'quiz') 
                               AND qnr.uid IN ( 
                                              # Return all uid's in the class 
                                              SELECT ogm.etid 
                                               FROM   `og_membership` AS ogm 
                                               WHERE  gid = 983 
                                                      AND entity_type = 'user' 
                                                      AND field_name = 
                                                          'og_user_node') 
                        GROUP  BY qnr.nid, 
                                  qnr.uid 
                        ORDER  BY qnr.uid, 
                                  session_count DESC) t 
                GROUP  BY t.uid) t2)                                AS 
       courses_started, 
       (SELECT Count(opigno_statistics_user_course_pk) 
        FROM   `opigno_statistics_user_course` 
        WHERE  course_nid = node.nid 
               AND uid IN ( 
                          # Return all uid's in the class 
                          SELECT ogm.etid 
                           FROM   `og_membership` AS ogm 
                           WHERE  gid = 983 
                                  AND entity_type = 'user' 
                                  AND field_name = 'og_user_node')) AS 
       courses_completed 
FROM   node node 
       INNER JOIN field_data_opigno_class_courses AS 
                  field_data_opigno_class_courses 
               ON node.nid = 
                  field_data_opigno_class_courses.opigno_class_courses_target_id 
                  AND ( field_data_opigno_class_courses.entity_type = 'node' 
                        AND field_data_opigno_class_courses.deleted = '0' ) 
       INNER JOIN node opigno_class_courses_node 
               ON field_data_opigno_class_courses.entity_id = 
                  opigno_class_courses_node.nid 
WHERE  ( (( opigno_class_courses_node.nid = '983' )) 
         AND ((( node.status = '1' ))) ) 
ORDER  BY node_created DESC
```

Comment: Start by giving an alias (say n1, n2, ...) to each instance of node in the question.

Comment: To expand on Lennart's comment; here, the t2 subquery include the table `node`, and the t subquery inside it also refers to `node`, leaving the `qnr.nid IN` subquery unclear on which `node` table's value it should refer to.  **ALSO** - the `node`, `t` query and the `qnr`, `node` query are both going to be `CROSS JOIN` queries, since there's nothing that tells the engine how to match the rows. This may be deliberate, but seems worth mentioning.

Comment: `IN ( SELECT ... )` performs poorly; turn it into a `JOIN`.

Comment: I've aliased every `node` instance to `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, `n4`. Still, I'm getting the `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'node.nid' in 'where clause'` error.

Comment: I've updated my original question, including the entire resulting (first excluded from question) query.

Comment: Just starting from your inner query to try to point you in the right direction:

```SELECT n4.nid FROM ... JOIN `node` AS n4 ... WHERE  gid = node.nid```

There is no node.nid in that as you have aliased it in the join to n4. So that isn't going to work in the WHERE clause.

I think you probably should be rejigging all this with JOINs but if you want just quick and dirty and what you actually want to do there is "gid=983" then I would suggest just setting it as a variable up the top and referencing the variable, i.e. ```SET @myid= 983;``` up top and then ```WHERE gid = @myid```